# How to fix bugs of mtrr (Memory Type Range Registers) in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

My Python program causes my desktop crashed whenever it reaches the commands relating to reading images. The problem here is that the code works perfectly on a laptop having weaker hardware (Wins 10 64bit, RAM 4GB, CPU: i5-4250U 1.30 GHz 1.9Ghz) while crashing on the more powerful desktop (Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64bit, RAM 16GB, i7-4790 3.60GHz x 4). 
When I checked the syslog of the desktop, I found some errors of mtrr. Although I googled and found some explanations for mtrr (Memory Type Range Registers), I still feel so confused about how to fix my problem.

This is a cut from my /var/log/syslog file: [File syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ocn2AglEhQ6hmrK5j9GanQ0dzx_gsATH/view?usp=sharing)

I put the following questions into the same post because I think they're related to each other and all of them are about mtrr.

---

I found in /var/log/syslog the following error messages relating to mtrr:

```
(1) mtrr_cleanup: can not find optimal value
    please specify mtrr_gran_size/mtrr_chunk_size
    ...
(2) Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
    ...
(3) mtrr: type mismatch for e0000000,800000 old: write-back new: write-combining
```

1. I googled and found that to fix this one, I need to add settings for mtrr_cleanup similar to the following:

> enable_mtrr_cleanup mtrr_spare_reg_nr=1 mtrr_gran_size=16M
>   mtrr_chunk_size=64M

I know I can choose values for mtrr_gran_size and mtrr_chunk_size from the list of options in the file syslog but I'm confused about which one to choose.
(My computer info: Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64bit, RAM 16GB, i7-4790 3.60GHz x 4).

2. Is this row is an error?
3. I haven't known how to fix this error.

Hope someone can help me to fix the errors or at least the first one. Thank you so much.